# How to test text on rendered view?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

Here is my test:

```
require "rspec"

describe HomeController do
  render_views

  it "should renders the home" do
    get :home
    response.should render_template("home")
    response.should include_text("Simulate Circuits Online")
  end

end
```

but, I got:

```
1) HomeController should renders the home
     Failure/Error: response.should include_text("Some text to be test ..")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `include_text' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xd429a0c>
     # ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # (eval):6:in `block in fork'
     # (eval):6:in `fork'
     # (eval):6:in `fork'
```

So, what's the right way to test the text rendered?

**EDIT**
If I try  `response.should have_content("My text ..")`

I get

```
1) HomeController should renders the home
     Failure/Error: response.should have_content("My text ..")
       expected there to be text "My text .." in "#"
     # ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view template do you actually have the text you are checking for? The error seems to be that it couldn't actually find the text.

Also, try using `response.should have_text`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
response.should have_content("Simulate Circuits Online")
```

Comment: I searched for text matchers for RSpec, but, I couldn't find any, can you please point me where to read?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the DOM element's attributes and content.

```
expect(page).to have_selector 'h1', :text => 'Your text here'
```

This method doesn't retrieve any deprecations warnings.